# Sort an array and replace the values w.r.t index

Tags: c#, arrays, windows-phone-7, sorting

I have got a weird situation. There is an array that has got numbers from 1 - 20, the other array has got all the random numbers. Using Array.Sort(rand) I'm able to sort the randnos array. But how can I give a rank to those numbers using the numbers array.

Should I use the sorting algorithms? Or are there any available stuff?

Comment: What do you mean, "give a rank to those numbers"?

Comment: Among the random numbers, based on the ascending order.. The lower value gets one, the higher value gets higher value and so on.

Comment: Please provide an example with 5 numbers in each array to show what you mean. Right now it's confusing.

Comment: So you want the rank of the numbers to be in a new array or what?

Comment: int [] nos = {1,2,3,4,5};
int [] rand = 5 random no.s suppose 112,10,33,42,90.
These random numbers are to be ranked like 10-1,33-2,42-3,90-4,112-5.

Comment: @ChibuezeOpata yes sir... I need that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given an array of random numbers:

```
var rand = new Random();
    // generate an array of 10 random numbers between 1 and 100
var randNumbers = Enumerable.Range(1,10)                  // enumerable 1 to 10
                            .Select(_ => rand.Next(100))  // replace with random num
                            .ToArray();                   // convert to array
```

Here is a method to sort them and provide their rank, as a string `number-rank`:

```
var sorted = randNumbers.OrderBy(x => x)                   // sort by the number
                        .Select((val,idx) =>               // given the value and the index
                                 String.Format("{0}-{1}",  // return value-index as string
                                        val,idx+1))
                        .ToArray();                        // convert to array
```

Prints (for example):

```
21-1 
30-2 
31-3 
32-4 
40-5 
51-6 
67-7 
70-8 
84-9 
99-10
```

Note that you could also have done:

```
randNumbers.Sort() // sort in place first
var sorted = ... // same as above without the OrderBy
```

Comment: Commenting the code, especially the LINQ and Lambda parts will help? @yamen

Comment: Happy to obglige @ChibuezeOpata but please also read up on any LINQ commands you're not familiar with. They will only improve your code.

Comment: Good, the answer looks much better now.

Answer (score 0):

What does this actually accomplish?  The "rank" you're looking for, based on your description, is just the array index after it's been sorted.  There's no reason to involve a second array at all.

I can see this being somewhat useful if your "rank" array contains something other than the sequence of natural numbers.  If you have two arrays that need to be sorted in the same order, there's an overload of `Array.Sort()` that will provide this functionality.  See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0h22cx4f.aspx) MSDN article for reference.  All you'd need to do is call `Array.Sort(rand, ranks)`

Comment: I'm displaying those random numbers, simply I want to give a rank below that. So how can I do that